How to find out if Nextflow run has been cancelled via Tower
I am launching a Nextflow pipeline through Nextflow Tower, and want to inform users when a pipeline starts/finishes/fails. There are three types of failures I want to distinguish between:

One of the processes in pipeline fails or is terminated by host.
Head job fails or is terminated by host.
The run is cancelled by user via NFTower web UI.

Depending on which one happened, I want to send an email in workflow.onComplete (i.e. from within pipeline). Process failure is easy to identify - it populates workflow.exitStatus variable with whatever non-zero code the process returned. But head job failure (due to something like SLURM on HPC host deciding to kill Nextflow) and user-initiated cancellation look the same for the pipeline: workflow.exitStatus is null because no task has returned non-zero exit code, and workflow.errorMessage is SIGINT. Is there any way to tell whether a given run was killed by HPC host or NFTower?
